# Unexpected result : "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am learning django restframework for the first time , and I am not able to debug this error since a while , please help in debugging this issue.
Thanks!

```
HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."
}
```

Here is my code of views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics, status
from .serializers import RoomSerializer, CreateRoomSerializer
from .models import Room
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response


class RoomView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Room.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RoomSerializer


class CreateRoomView(APIView):
    serializer_class = CreateRoomSerializer

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        if not self.request.session.exists(self.request.session.session_key):
            self.request.session.create()

        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            guest_can_pause = serializer.data.get('guest_can_pause')
            votes_to_skip = serializer.data.get('votes_to_skip')
            host = self.request.session.session_key
            queryset = Room.objects.filter(host=host)
            if queryset.exists():
                room = queryset[0]
                room.guest_can_pause = guest_can_pause
                room.votes_to_skip = votes_to_skip
                room.save(update_fields=['guest_can_pause', 'votes_to_skip'])
                return Response(RoomSerializer(room).data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                room = Room(host=host, guest_can_pause=guest_can_pause,
                            votes_to_skip=votes_to_skip)
                room.save()
```

Comment: you not implement **GET** method for that end-point and you request a GET api call. Due to this error comes

Answer (score 0):

You need a get method within the CreateRoomView class if you want your class to be able to handle GET requests

```
class CreateRoomView(APIView):
    serializer_class = CreateRoomSerializer

    def get(self, request, format=None):
       ...
```

If you are getting this error while trying to make a POST request on the client-side, then make sure you are making a POST request instead of a GET request to your servers

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem at all. Because when you hit the url in browser, initially it calls GET method. But you haven't implemented it in your APIView. To be a safe side, by convention, you get add a GET method for list of all your instances. like,

```
class CreateRoomView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        rooms = Room.objects.all()
        serializer = RoomSerializer(rooms, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        if not self.request.session.exists(self.request.session.session_key):
            self.request.session.create()

        serializer = CreateRoomSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            guest_can_pause = serializer.data.get('guest_can_pause')
            votes_to_skip = serializer.data.get('votes_to_skip')
            host = self.request.session.session_key
            queryset = Room.objects.filter(host=host)
            if queryset.exists():
                room = queryset[0]
                room.guest_can_pause = guest_can_pause
                room.votes_to_skip = votes_to_skip
                room.save(update_fields=['guest_can_pause', 'votes_to_skip'])
                return Response(RoomSerializer(room).data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                room = Room(host=host, guest_can_pause=guest_can_pause,
                        votes_to_skip=votes_to_skip)
                room.save()
```